# How to setup Websocket in Blazor Server?

Tags: websocket, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create a WebSocket Server in my Blazor Server application, here it is my Program.cs:

```
...
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
        {
            if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                var webSocketHandler = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IWebSocketHandler>();
                await webSocketHandler.HandleWebSocketAsync(context, webSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    });
    var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
    {
        KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
    
    };
    
    app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
    
    ...
```

I am trying to test it using the WebSocketClient chrome extension. However, the connection request is blocked because `context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest` is `false`!

I enabled allow-insecure-localhost and also ran dotnet dev-certs https --trust...
I tried changing the port in the launchSettings.json; all the same result

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SignalR for web sockets?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-8.0&WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website

Comment: I need to prepare a WebSocket Server to allow connection from old client who only connects to WebSocket

Comment: Ok, will SignalR not do that? I know there are options tell signalR to just use the websocket transport and not the other fallback types.

Answer (score 0):

The `app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);` should occur before the verification of conditions and Map.